# Different results with group_by() and n() (paste0)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to ass a counting tag to an ID. Therefore i group my data and if a group has more than one row a counting tag is added. The indicator for the counting is done by `dplyr::n()`. If the `n()` is used outside of `paste0()` my code works, if its used inside, the code does not work. What is the reason for the different results?

**n() outside paste0() --> right result**

```
tibble::tibble(Group = c("A","A","B","C"),
               ID = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_10", "ID_20")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(n = dplyr::n(),
                tag = ifelse(n > 1, 
                             paste0(ID, " #", dplyr::row_number()),
                             ID)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

A tibble: 4 x 4
  Group ID        n tag    
  <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>  
1 A     ID_1      2 ID_1 #1
2 A     ID_2      2 ID_2 #2
3 B     ID_10     1 ID_10  
4 C     ID_20     1 ID_20
```

**n() inside paste0() --> wrong result** (tags are both ID_1 #1)

```
tibble::tibble(Group = c("A","A","B","C"),
               ID = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_10", "ID_20")) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(tag = ifelse(dplyr::n() > 1, 
                             paste0(ID, " #", dplyr::row_number()),
                             ID)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

A tibble: 4 x 3
  Group ID    tag    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 A     ID_1  ID_1 #1
2 A     ID_2  ID_1 #1
3 B     ID_10 ID_10  
4 C     ID_20 ID_20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the condition `n() > 1` is of length 1 and `ifelse` returns a vector which is of same length as the condition we are checking. You can try `if`/`else` here :

```
tibble::tibble(Group = c("A","A","B","C"),
           ID = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_10", "ID_20")) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Group) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(tag = if(n() > 1) paste0(ID, " #", dplyr::row_number()) 
                  else ID) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Group ID    tag    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1 A     ID_1  ID_1 #1
#2 A     ID_2  ID_2 #2
#3 B     ID_10 ID_10  
#4 C     ID_20 ID_20
```

In your first attempt the condition is `n > 1` for first group (`Group == A`) which has length 2 whereas in second case the condition is `n() > 1` and has length of only 1 hence only 1 value is generated (`ID_1 #1`) and recycled for other row.